# Why 入った and not 入た past tense

Tags: verbs, conjugations, tense, past

I've learned that ru verbs should drop る and replace it with た.

But 入る becomes 入った and I'm not sure why.

The same goes for

- 食べる → 食べた
- しゃべる → しゃべた

Are these irregulars or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Note that しゃべる is a _godan_ verb, and the past しゃべった and conjunctive しゃべって both have geminate (doubled) "t" consonants.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### tl;dr

入る *hairu* is a consonant-stem verb, i.e. *hair·u*.

#### Long version

Besides a handful of exceptions, there are two type of verbs

- vowel-stem verbs (*-e·ru*, *-i·ru*)
- consonant-stem verbs (*-k·u*, *-g·u*, *-s·u*, *-t·u*, *-n·u*, *-(w)·u*, *-m·u*, *-r·u*)

where I have used an interpunct · to separate the stem from the ending (and the hyphen - means there is more coming before it).

These types follow **different inflection patterns**.

Of course there are no pure consonants in *kana*, so written in *kana* you cannot show where the border between stem and ending is — for example a verb ending in ～く may inflect to ～か (as in 聞**く** → 聞**か**ない), but written as above, the stem ending in *-k* does not change (*kik·u* → *kik·anai*). (This is why it is called the stem. And the stem of vowel-stem/consonant-stem verbs end in a vowel/consonant, respectively.)

Now, seeing a verb written in *kana*, there is no way of telling whether a verb ending in *-eru* / *-iru* is a vowel-stem verb or a consonant stem verb, i.e. whether it is *-e·ru* / *-i·ru* or *-er·u* / *-ir·u*.

The following vowel-stem–consonant-stem verb pairs show that this difference simply has to be learned:

- 着る *ki·ru* ↔ 切る *kir·u*
- 変える *kae·ru* ↔ 帰る *kaer·u*

In particular, their past tenses are different

- 着た *kita* ↔ 切った *kitta*
- 変えた *kaeta* ↔ 帰った *kaetta*

Now, 入る is *hair·u* (i.e. a consonant-stem verb), so its past tense follows the same pattern as 切る, giving 入った.

However, the way the verb is written in *kanji* gives some way of guessing whether it is vowel-stem or consonant-stem. As a rule of thumb (for verbs of three or more morae), if the *-i* or *-e* is part of the *kanji*, then a verb is more likely to be consonant-stem.

In particular, since はいる is a three mora verb, written 入る rather than *入いる, it is more likely to be consonant-stem. The rule also correctly identifies 食べる as a vowel-stem verb (→ 食べた) and 喋る【しゃべる】 as a consonant-stem verb (→ 喋**っ**た).

Comment: Jinx!  :) .......

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi ハッピーアイスクリームお返しなし! =)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Although @EiríkrÚtlendi his answer was very clear as well, I found your's just a bit easier to understand. But thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 7):

The name "*ru* verb" is misleading.

This does **not** mean that every verb ending in *-ru* conjugates the same way.

Certain verbs end in *-ru*, and that final *-ru* disappears in entirety when conjugating.  These are called **一段活用** (*ichidan katsuyō*, literally "monograde conjugation" or "one-step conjugation") verbs in Japanese grammars, because there is only one vowel on the end of the verb stem (either *-i* or *-e*).  These are often labeled as "**type 2**" verbs in English texts about Japanese grammar.

One everyday example is 食べる (*taberu*, "to eat"), where that final *-ru* just disappears entirely in conjugated forms:

- *tabe**ru*** "[I / he / she / they] eat", plain informal
- *tabenai* "[I / he / she / they] don't / doesn't eat", plain negative
- *tabemasu* "[I / he / she / they] eat", polite
- *tabesaseru* "[I / he / she / they] make someone eat", plain causative

... etc.  As you can see here, the *-ru* vanishes entirely in the conjugated forms.

Other verbs end in *-ru* or *-ku* or *-su*, etc., and that final piece doesn't quite vanish entirely -- the consonant remains, but the vowel changes.  These are called **五段活用** (*godan katsuyō*, literally "quintigrade conjugation" or "five-step conjugation") verbs in Japanese grammars, because there are five different possible vowels on the end of the verb stem (*-a*, *-i*, *-u*, *-e*, *-o*).  These are often labeled as "**type 1**" verbs in English texts about Japanese grammar.

One everyday example with *-ru* is 入る (*hairu*, "to enter, to go into"), where that final *-ru* doesn't disappear entirely, and only the vowel changes:

- *hai**ru*** "[I / he / she / they] enter", plain informal
- *hai**r**anai* "[I / he / she / they] don't / doesn't enter", plain negative
- *hai**r**imasu* "[I / he / she / they] enter", polite
- *hai**r**aseru* "[I / he / she / they] make someone enter", plain causative

As you can see here, the *-r-* sticks around, and the vowel changes.

Things ultimately get a bit more complicated than this (such as the conjunctive forms and plain past forms, where you often get geminate [i.e. doubled] consonants instead of the final consonant, as in *haitta*), but that's the basic framework.  There's good information on Wikipedia, at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation.

Answer (score 2):

The rule for '-ru' (ichidan) verbs and '-u' (godan) verbs is 'anything ending in '-iru' or '-eru' *can* be a '-ru' verb. But 入る and しゃべる are not; they are '-u' verbs that conjugate as you would expect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I missed that they can be godan. Would they count as irregulars? Our does that happen a lot?